# c++ - Nuklear GUI can't make labels with several rows

Tags: c++, user-interface

I'm trying to output several rows of text in label but it seems to not recognize \n as a valid symbol. Good example of such would be this example

```
nk_layout_row_dynamic(ctx, 200, 1);
nk_label(ctx, "row1\nrow2\nfinal row", NK_TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
```

You would expect it to display

```
row1
row2
final row
```

Instead it just shows

```
row1?row2?final row
```

There is a workaround with using nk_text_edit but that would require a bit of a rewrite, as it doesn't allow to work with std::string as nk_label does.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear/issues/532

Seems to be a well known missing feature